# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: hoc_age]
[image: fredley]
[image: Sam Whited]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

**Almost certainly**. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why we eventually hold elections.

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

#### Update - June 2015:

Sam Whited has resigned his moderator diamond. We wish him the best and thank him for his excellent service!

In his place, another community member has volunteered to step up to the plate. Please join me in welcoming:

[image: Nick Udell]

Comment: Let's give them a round of applause!

Comment: Amazing I must say! What happens if they are less than 16 years of age though? The youngest moderator that actually works for SE is 13 years...

Comment: @PythonMaster `[citation-needed]`

Comment: I have seen fredley at Arqade and Coffee and he's quite good. I don't know about anyone else, though.

Comment: First of congratulations to the moderators. I don't mean to speak out of turn here but I was wondering if I might submit myself as a candidate for moderation. I have never been a moderator on SE but I have indeed participated in numerous SE sites. I would be more than willing to serve as a moderator, especially under the wing of a more experienced moderator such as fredley. Is there any way that I can be considered for this? I have a lot of experience with coffee as I was a professional barista for 2 years. Again if I am speaking out of turn, please forgive me.

Comment: @fredley The guy's Doorknob. Appointed a mod of PCG at 13 years and some months. I'm just 14 anyway. :3

Answer (score 9):

Since there wasn't a nomination post, I think it'd be nice if we introduce ourselves.

I'm fredley, I've been a mod on Arqade for a year already, and a member of Stack Exchange for nearly five years. I live and work in London, and my office currently has no coffee making facilities in it at all :-(

[image: profile for Tom Medley on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

At home, I make my coffee with my trusty Bialetti moka pot, but I've had espresso machines in the past and hope to have another soon.

When it comes to moderation, I'm a quality fanatic - I will edit a lot, but do call me out if you think I've gone too far. During waking hours (GMT) I'm usually hailable in chat.

In terms of growing the community, I believe if we can create great content, people will find us, and if we're welcoming they'll stay. If we can keep it up for the next few months as the beta proceeds, I don't see why we can't carry this site to graduation and beyond!

[image]

Comment: When it comes to moderation, I'm a *precision* fanatic; please pardon my trivial spelling edit. It didn't previously occur to me how odd this would look with me listed as an edit of @fredley's self-introduction post. *Mea culpa*, and *mea*... um, learning. ;-)

Comment: @fredley You got 100 rep in 48 hours. Whoa...

Answer (score 7):

I shall follow suit!

I'm hoc_age, and I like coffee and Science. I enjoy learning and understanding the nature of the (coffee) universe; to that end, I like explanations that have a basis in demonstrable fact  (though [not exclusively](https://coffee.meta.stackexchange.com/a/79/262) :). I experiment with different coffee preparation and enjoyment methods as a vehicle. I also like cooking (and Science) and contribute to [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com). I have a tendency to be pedantic and verbose, but I also try to be conscientious and receptive: if you don't like what I say or how I say it, please tell me!

More broadly, I'm a relatively new "active" user (~1 year) to Stack Exchange. I am a huge proponent of the *learning-based* approach to Stack Exchange, and am a big believer in effort and engagement in a community. I wish I could wear my ["Warm Welcome" hat](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/) year 'round. See [my original meta-missive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/3562032) for more of my philosophy.

I'm rarely the [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/262760), so I (*try* to...) try to take the opposite approach: make a smaller number of higher-quality posts. I originally heard this philosophy as pertains to scientific papers; the original author was lamenting (a perception) that scientists were trying to write as many papers as possible, as quickly as possible (for any number of perceived reasons: funding, relevance, legitimacy, pressure, e-peen, ...) I.e., without as much regard for their content, quality, or profoundness. SE is structured to enhance and enforce quality. Let's make this the best coffee-site possible!

Comment: I am 5 month user. We should have more mods though :-).

Answer (score 7):

Yay — my power's back on! After a day in the dark, I can finally introduce myself.

I'm Sam; some of you may already know me from other sites in the SE network. I've also got the diamond over on [Tor.SE](https://tor.stackexchange.com), and occasionally go on ask/answer binges over at [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com). I currently hail from Atlanta, GA (but not for long as I'm moving to Austin, TX this very weekend to start a new job in software engineering).

I have a french press and espresso machine sitting on my desk at all times (and a tea kettle on the stove heating up water for the french press, of course), and generally prefer my coffee black. My favorite roasts are [Batdorf & Bronson](http://www.batdorfcoffee.com/)'s "Dancing Goats" (makes a seriously good cup of espresso) and anything from the [Atlanta Coffee Roasters](http://atlantacoffeeroasters.com/) in the press pot or on drip (I used to practically live in their store-front / coffee shop back when I worked from home). I also recently did a thru-hike of the Appalachian trail, where I learned that it's always possible to make cowboy coffee in the woods if you try hard enough.

I'm looking forward to working with you all to build a great community.

[image: profile for Sam Whited on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Answer (score 5):

everybody!

I'm Nick, I'm new, and I love coffee, something that probably earns me the badge of "traitor" in my tea-loving home-nation of Britain. When it comes to coffee-related knowledge though, I'm a complete beginner, so expect me to be doing more asking than answering around here.

I'm a scientist and programmer by day, and an independent game developer by night. If there are any occupations fuelled more by caffeine than those, let me know so I can add them to my CV.

I'm active on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and especially [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), and I'm very proud to call this wonderful site home. You can also find me sticking my oar in where it's not wanted over on various Area51 proposals.

I prefer my coffees milky and frothy, but I'm slowly coming around to richer, stronger flavours. Who knows, maybe you'll make a black coffee drinker out of me yet!